# Force close when I change position of xml elements

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to re-organize one of my activities. Basicaly all I want to do is move a linearlayout element and text element from the bottom of the page to the middle. But when I do and run my app I get this error:

```
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.beerportfoliopro/com.example.beerportfoliopro.BeerPage}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.BeerPage.onCreate(BeerPage.java:49)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
06-26 13:37:38.385: E/AndroidRuntime(11578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
```

My original xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"/>



    <TableLayout  

    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*"> 

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableStatTitles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abvTitle"
            android:text="ABV"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IBUTitle"
            android:text="IBU"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/glassTitle"
            android:text="Glass"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>


        </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableStat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abv"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IBU"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/glass"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>


        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout> 







    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBrewery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text=""
        android:onClick="viewBrewery"
        />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text=""
        android:onClick="viewStyle"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDescriptionTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="Description:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="5dip"

        ></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourPortfolio"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Your Portfolio:"
        android:padding="5dip"
        ></TextView>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/addBeerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The one I want and the one that force closes the app is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"/>



    <TableLayout  

    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*"> 

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableStatTitles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abvTitle"
            android:text="ABV"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IBUTitle"
            android:text="IBU"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/glassTitle"
            android:text="Glass"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>


        </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableStat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abv"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IBU"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/glass"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>


        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout> 







    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBrewery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text=""
        android:onClick="viewBrewery"
        />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text=""
        android:onClick="viewStyle"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourPortfolio"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Your Portfolio:"
        android:padding="5dip"
        ></TextView>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/addBeerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDescriptionTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="Description:"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="5dip"

        ></TextView>



</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you haven't changed your `id's` in xml or Java, you may just need to clean your project

> Project --> Clean...  then pick your project

Sometimes Eclipse doesn't pick up xml changes right away so it throws these class cast exceptions. Simply cleaning and rebuilding the project usually takes care of such errors. Its a quick and easy thing to do before pulling out all of your hair trying to figure out why you would get such an exception.

Answer (score 1):

From the second line in your logcat: "...android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView..." it seems that in your java code you are trying to cast LinearLayout to TextView. Perhaps you are doing something like:

```
... = (LinearLayout)findViewById(<some id>);
```

and it should be like:

```
... = (TextView)findViewById(<some id>);
```

To be honest I didn't read your layouts xml but this particular problem is in your java code and not in the xml.

Hope this helps...

Comment: the odd thing is it only happens when I change the layout.

Comment: So follow codeMagics suggestion and see how it goes. Otherwise double check your ids...